# How do I POST multiple values with the same key (to Google Translate) using the simple C# WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, google-translate

I wish to send multiple values to the Google Translate API using the simple syntax provided by the C# `WebClient`. To send multiple values to the API, each value has to have the same query-string key, for example: `q=value1&q=value2`.

I cannot use the default GET mechanism and simply put these values on the query-string because some of my values are too large. I therefore have to POST these values making sure I set the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.

The problem is, to POST my values I need to use the `WebClient.UploadValues()` method which expects the values to be presented as a `NameValueCollection`. Multiple values with the same key are supported by the `NameValueCollection` but not in a way that the Google Translate API will recognise as separate values (it creates a simple comma delimited set of values held under a single key unique key).

How do I POST multiple values, each with the same key, using the `WebClient` class?

For further reading see:

- [Google Translate V2 cannot handle large text translations from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093971/776476)
- [When making a POST call using a WebClient, how do I send
  duplicate values in the NameValueCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18541944/776476)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use the `WebClient.UploadString()` method, although there are a couple of gotchas to note. First some code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");
    webClient.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = string.Format("key={0}&source={1}&target={2}&q={3}&q={4}", myApiKey, "en", "fr", urlEncodedValue1, urlEncodedvalue2);
    try
    {
        var json = webClient.UploadString(GoogleTranslateApiUrl, "POST", data);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        translatedValue1 = result.data.translations[0].translatedText;
        translatedValue2 = result.data.translations[1].translatedText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        loggingService.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You can see that I am formatting the data to be sent to the Google Translate API as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string. This allows  multiple values with the same key to be formatted together.

To post this correctly You must remember to set the `WebClient.Encoding` property, in my case to `UTF8`, as the `WebClient` converts the string to be uploaded into an array of bytes before posting them.

You must also remember to set the `content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` thus ensuring the payload is correctly packaged.

Finally you have to remember to urlencode the values to to be translated.